# Python module import : what about modules imported in the imported module

Tags: python, import

Sorry about putting this probably naive question. I tried to look for doc and do some experiments, but I wanted to make sure that this is the case:

If, in file test.py, I had:

```
import module1
```

And I do this in console:

```
import test
```

I would not import the module1 in the console.

And if I do this:

```
from test import *
```

Also, module1 would not be imported into the console.

Is that correct?
Thanks!

Comment: Both of them would import `module1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import test
```

This only imports the name `test` into the current namespace. Anything in `test`'s namespace is accessible as `test.whatever`; in particular, `module1` is available as `test.module1`, though you shouldn't use that.

```
from test import *
```

This imports everything that doesn't start with an underscore from `test`'s namespace into the current one. Since `module1` is available in `test`'s namespace, this does import the name `module1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your experiment can be conducted very easily from the shell:

```
╭─phillip@phillip-laptop  ~ ‹ruby-1.9.3@global› ‹pandas›
╰─$ echo "import module1" > test.py
╭─phillip@phillip-laptop  ~ ‹ruby-1.9.3@global› ‹pandas›
╰─$ touch module1.py
╭─phillip@phillip-laptop  ~ ‹ruby-1.9.3@global› ‹pandas›
╰─$ py
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 17 2013, 07:55:04)
[GCC 4.8.0 20130502 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> test.module1
<module 'module1' from 'module1.py'>
>>> from test import *
>>> module1
<module 'module1' from 'module1.py'>
```